# cannot use theme color by muiThemeProvider tag in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a React-redux app project and I'm new to material-ui theming. I created a theme object in a separate theme.js file, outlined as follows:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: blue,
        error: {
            main: red[300],
        },
        background: {
            default: indigo[50],
        },
    }
})
export default theme;
```

And I rendered `MuiThemeProvider` in my outer layer of the app in index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My question is that, my app's currently showing the correct background color but I don't know how to properly use the color I created in my palette in other parts of my app. For example, I tried to assign the primary color blue to a title in App.js:

```
 <CardContent color="primary">
       TITLE
 </CardContent>
```

But it didn't work. Everything's imported properly. No error. The font color isn't changed. Any idea?

By the way, I've seen tutorial using `ThemeProvider` tag, what's the difference between `ThemeProvider` and `MuiThemeProvider`, which one do you recommend using in general?

Comment: My answer was not good, you can use the full blue color object...

Comment: @ Charles dB I tried using primary the other way but still didn't work... :/ I don't think that's where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the theming probably, From Material-ui documentation Card Content doesn't accept the color parameter

[Card Content](https://material-ui.com/api/card-content/)

I would try :

```
<CardContent>
    <Typography color="primary">
        Hello world
    </Typography>
</CardContent>
```

Comment: Yes! it's working after I added Typography tag. Thanks so much. Your answer probably have solved several of my questions on theming. It's making more sense now.

Comment: By the way is there any resources on whether a certain component in material-ui accepts any specific type of parameter, instead of going over the official doc?

Comment: I like the official doc :-), in VisualStudio, it's telling me the accepted parameters in the autocomplete

Comment: I'm also using VisualStudio code, did you get any extensions for material-ui?

Comment: Ok. Anyway, I'll keep finding while reading more official doc :) Thanks!